# How are the datanodes communicates with each other in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Unlike rpc communication between client to namenode or between namenode and datanode, the datanodes seems have their own way to communicate each other.

So how are datanodes communicate to each other? Is their any related material on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main communications between datanodes is data transfers, replicating blocks from one datanode to one or more other nodes.

If you have the source to hand, you can look in `DataNode.DataTransfer.run()`. The 0.20.2 version (which i have the source to hand), connects to the target data nodes (one at a time), sends a header and then the block bytes.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataNode.java?view=markup

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help! I am reading the source code and kind of confused about communication between datanodes.